# axios returning no server response despite Satus 200

Tags: reactjs, axios, formik

So I'm trying to create a login form with formik and axios

```js
const LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost:8081/api/authenticate';

//

const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object({
    password: Yup.string()//.oneOf([Yup.ref('confirmPassword')], 'Mot de passe différent!')
      .required('Champ obligatoire'),
    username: Yup.string().required('Champ obligatoire'),
  }),
});
```

```js
const { setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
const userRef = useRef();
const errRef = useRef();

const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');
const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  userRef.current.focus();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  setErrMsg('');
}, [username, password])

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL,
      formik.values,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==',
          'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:*/',
        },
        withCredentials: true
      }
    );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(response?.data));
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    const accessToken = response?.data?.accessToken;
    const roles = response.data.roles;
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.data);
    setAuth({username,password,roles,accessToken});
    setUsername('');
    setPassword('');
    setSuccess(true);


  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.response) {
      setErrMsg('No Server Response');
      console.log(err.response.status);

    } else if (err.response.status === 400) {
      setErrMsg('Missing Username or Password');

    } else if (err.response.status === 401) {
      setErrMsg('Unauthorized');

    } else if (err.response.status === 404) {
      setErrMsg('NOT FOUND');

    } else {
      setErrMsg('Login Failed');

    }
    errRef.current.focus();
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

the problem is it gets the access token it returns Status 200 but after that it just says no Server response and when you console log the error it says undefined??

[image: Console Log]

same code works fine on an other react page (landing page)

Comment: What's the desire output? Is server suppose to send some kind of response with some data? or only status code? Error says `undefined` and after that it's saying `setAuth is not a function at handleSubmit`

Comment: well the desired output is that success variable value gets true and it just sends a message I put in render() part, like i said the problem that vexes me is that the same code works just fine and i managed to login on another react app